# Redirecting in rails 'uninitialized constant MembersController' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, crud

I have a app that is using the devise gem. I have two models which are members and trip. Every member has one trip. After a member is signed in or signed up, I want them to be redirected to the trip new page where they can create a trip. I have it redirecting, but it's not carrying over the member id in the url and I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried it every way that I know how and right now I'm getting a members controller error and even when I generate one it still doesn't work. Not sure if devise has to do with this or not.

This is the controller with the method that determines what happens after someone signs up

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      new_member_trip_path(current_member.id)
    end
end
```

These are the rake routes

```
 new_member_trip GET    /members/:member_id/trip/new(.:format)      trip#new
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  "/members/#{current_member.id}/trip/new"
end
```

but i think that better way to do it is just calling `new_member_trip_path`

edit: ok, i checked it and it works for me:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    #log in after register
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #redirect to new trip page after log in
    new_member_trip_path(current_member)
  end
```

Comment: how can I do it with new_member_trip_path ??

Comment: I'm getting a 'NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#create' when I do this:


url_for new_member_trip(current_member)

Comment: Because I've forgotten about `_path`, also `url_for` is not necessary. (edited)

Comment: Awesome!! thank you. How did you figure that out? Been working on this for an hour... why would I even need: after_sign_in_path_for(resource) ? I thought I can just put: new_member_trip_path(current_member)

Comment: I am glad I could help. Devise by default doesn't login after registration so you can't refer to the current user's id(or member in your case). Calling `after_sign_in` in `after_sign_up` may looks a little strange but it works it out. :)

Comment: Nice! And just for clarification, if I wanted to route to the 'new_member_trip path after login too, how could I do that?

Comment: I got it to work for after_sign_in too, but it looks like that method needed to be put in the applications controller as opposed to the registrations controller. Any idea why?